# Data Transformation Using Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, database, powerbi

I have a large dataset, about 3600 rows, that contain product data.  Each one is a different line item with different $ values associated with it.  I am trying to consolidate this dataset into one row per unique account with all of the pricing data and products rolled up into one row.

What would be the best way using Excel or SQL or Microsoft Power BI to transform the first table into the desired table???  I can sort of do what I am thinking of by using a pivot table but it doesn't turn into a single row, though it does summarize like this.

Starting Table
[image: Starting Table]

Desired Table
[image: Desired Table]

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you didn't invite use to jump through hyperlinks to figure out what you want.

Comment: I just registered and it wouldn't let me directly post images... Sorry about that.  It's stackoverflow not me

Comment: The images are appearing now

Comment: You could improve this question by adding your start point as text to the question rather that showing the 'failed' outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it by Power Pivot:

[image]

Where `Product by Customer` is a Measure created by the formula:

```
=CONCATENATEX(Table2,[Product],"; ")
```

For larger dataset this seems to work better:

```
=CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Table2[Product]),Table2[Product],"; "))
```

---

To create the Measure:

Click on your pivot table and got to "Power Pivot", upper right corner. Then click "Measures" -> "Manage Measures..."

[image]

Click "New" and fill in with the formula.

*Notice I have "`;`" as delimiter but you might have "`,`".*

[image]

Comment: Yep. In Excel or Power BI, the `CONCATENATEX` function is the key.

Comment: Incredible.  This is the answer.  You are a life saver... I have spent hours pondering this.  This site is amazing I can't believe I never heard of it before!

Comment: I am still quite lost as to how to do all of this but you definitely have gotten the result that I want.

Comment: I have updated my answer how I created the "Measure" :)

Comment: I put all of my data into a table like you did, then set up a pivot table and created the formula exactly the same, but when I try to add Product by Customer to the Values section, it loads for a second and then unchecks the box.  It refuses to add to that section.

Comment: hmm... sounds strange. What Excel do you use?
You can see in my [mock example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/au63bo4e3zgesx8/Book2.xlsx?dl=0) how I have the setup.

Comment: It works on your example you sent... on my full data I did as follows.
1. Downloaded Power Pivot
2. Converted my 3600 row dataset into a table, including all columns that I want to pivot
3. Navigated to Power Pivot and clicked "Add to Data Model"
4. Clicked PivotTable in the pop-up window that comes up
5. Created the new measure using your instructions
6. Dragged and dropped the fields I wanted to display into the PivotTable Fields thing on the right side. 

What have I done wrong????

Comment: Do you use Excel 2010?

Comment: It is Excel 2016 x32.  I reconstructed my original example with the eggs and bacon and THAT works.  Why wouldn't it work with a very similar but much larger dataset?  Maybe not enough memory?

Comment: Good :)! On your way now! Then it's very strange. I'm on 2016 x64. Then this should definitly work... I was little confused why you need to download PowerPivot... I thought it's included since 2013. Anyway. Double check you data then is my suggestion, so you don't have weird cell formats etc.. (numbers/text mixed together in column).

Comment: Strange, I tried with 10 000 rows. However, I added another measure (slightly modified), please try it and see if it's work better for you with the larger dataset :)

Comment: THE NEW FORMULA WORKED!!!!  I'm not sure what the original formula didn't like about my data... I made it extremely uniform and nothing seemed to help.  Either way, I REALLY appreciate all of your help solving this.  You have saved us weeks of manual work... this will make me a hero, and you are MY hero.  Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems that the first is not stable with large data (I tried myself and I'm very suprised!!). So I put it in a Calculate function that makes excel to really evaluate the previous values/logic. The values make the output unique, less to process. Glad it worked and thank you :)!!! Just happy to help people :D!

Comment: But I want to believe that Excel likes Eggs and Bacon better ;). Take care :)!!